# Is there a way (or best practice) to markup the head (<th> equivalent) of a CSV document?

Tags: php, csv

I am exporting data from a database using PHP to convert it into a CSV. I figured it'd be useful to provide the first row with a title (similar to the `<th>` element in HTML) so the end user would understand the column's meanings. Example

```
=============
| id | name |
=============
| 0  | tim  |
| 1  | tom  |
=============
```

Which would look like this as a CSV

```
id, name
0, tim
1, tom
```

Is there a way to mark up the first row's columns or do anything differently that programs that often read CSVs (example Microsoft Excel) will mark it up accordingly.  I.e. provide a semantic hook to inform the client (possibly Excel but not restricted to) that this is a column header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. And to make it even more fun, there's nothing that says that the header line has to be present at all. Good times, good times...

Comment: I had a suspicion... Well at least with basic formats, less should go wrong (in theory at least :P)

Answer (score 3):

One key thing to avoid with CSVs is to avoid using 'ID' as the first characters in the file.  The lowercase 'id' or double-quoted '"ID"' is acceptable, but if Excel comes across upper-case 'ID' it tries to open the file as a SYLK file and fails.

(edit: note that single quotes in the above should be ignored)

Comment: I learned this the hard way a few years ago, it's a very annoying bug that won't get fixed

Answer (score 0):

The best practice I can think of myself is to make the headings the first row only. But this is obviously common sense.